# Web Site Character Set Issues

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am somewhat confused with this whole character set thingy. Everything seems fine when the data is inputting manually into the web sites and database tables. Except when data is inputted by copy and pasting – the character sets being to get screwy.

I asked several clients where there are getting this data from – the majority seems to be either from another web site or from a MS Document.

The characters that seem to be messing up are common characters like the following:

‘ © "

What is being inserted the the black triangle with the dreaded question mark! On my server I have the following settings.

PHP TIDY to clean the text before input to web page or database - output-encoding > UTF-8
Each web page has meta tag > charset=UTF-8
The database tables default > latin1_swedish_ci

I assume at first it was a database problem until I noticed that the same issue occurs with static web pages that are not database driven.

Help?

Comment: Let's start with [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: I've dealt with this issue before, and it was due to the characters being pasted from MS-Word (or any text editor that replaces normal characters with 'fancy' ones).. My solution was a `string_replace` on the offending characters.

Comment: MS Office tends to use CP125[0-2]. Just convert from those to UTF-8 and 99.8% of your problems will disappear.

Comment: ...and the other 0.2% of your problems will be solvable with a stiff drink and/or a good night's rest.

Comment: Thanks - I am read the web site now!

Comment: Perfect, that 99.8% conversion works - can I have a beer now!

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a good solution to replace away the smart quotes. If you can't cope with smart quotes or the copyright symbol, you can't cope with any other non-ASCII characters either, leaving you with an ASCII-only application (which these days is a pretty sad thing).

Instead you should ideally ensure that your web application using UTF-8 throughout, which means:

1. Serve all your pages as UTF-8 using a `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and/or a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`.
2. Ensure your .php source files are saved as UTF-8, if they contain any non-ASCII characters themselves.
3. Use `mysql_set_charset('utf-8')` when connecting to the database.
4. Ensure your MySQL tables are created with a UTF-8 `CHARACTER SET`/`COLLATION`. They won't be by default if you didn't specify one when you created them. In this case you would need to `ALTER TABLE` on each text column to change it.
5. If you use `htmlentities()` to HTML-escape database content when putting it into the page, you need to pass in `utf-8` for the `$charset` argument or it will mangle all non-ASCII characters by treating them as ISO-8859-1 (which is *never* the proper encoding). Better: use `htmlspecialchars()` instead, which doesn't touch non-ASCII characters so doesn't care.